# TWRP backup directly to network drive

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, lan

I am trying to create a TWRP backup of my phone, but I don't have enough storage space to create the backup.  Is there some way to backup directly to an external drive on my local network, like I do with PC backups, or is that not possible on Android?

Comment: Came looking for the same answer.